# How to use javap with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javap

As the title states, I'm trying to use `javap` with eclipse but have difficulties setting it up. I'm trying to set it up using `external tools` from the `run` menu but can't find the correct `Arguments:` string to make it work. Basically I need something that will dynamically execute the current file I have opened.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use the following external tool configuration to achieve this:

[image]

`${system_path:javap}` is used to locate javap in the JDK used by the Eclipse. You can use an absolute path to javap instead.

`${project_loc}` returns the absolute path to the project. This is used, since I could not find a pre-define variable to use, to locate the `.class` file of a resource, and that's why `javap` runs in the project's directory instead of the directory containing the `.class` file.

Among the arguments passed to `javap`:

- `bin` is the default output folder for Eclipse projects. Change this to `build/classes` or whatever is used by the project. Note, the value is relative to `${project_loc}`; you can specify absolute paths instead.
- `${java_type_name}` is used to obtain the selected class name.

You can select a Java file in the Project explorer view or Project navigator view, or even a Java type in any of the views, and then run the external tool. Note - this approach doesn't work quite well when you select a method, an inner class etc. and then run the tool, as they are not resources on their own, leading to the scenario where `${project_loc}` will be empty.

Comment: +1 also updated picture to place `-c` before `ClassName` since parameters should be placed earlier. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Up-vote for the picture.  besides solution mentioned by  @AlexR,  Open the terminal windows  within the Ecplise and run the javap command with -p and other options.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem  is that javap requres path to class file but when you select your source file you can access eclipse variable `${selected_resource_loc}` contains path to java source.  As far as I understand there is no variable that contains path to class file.

I think that the easiest way for you is creating your custom script that accepts path to java file, replaces `java` to `class` and source folder to bin folder. If you are using linux it it can be easily done using command `sed`. If you are on windows it can be implemented using command `SET` with `~`. See help for more details.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by modify the `Working Directory` to match your java project output folder. In my case, it looks as given below.

Working Directory: `${workspace_loc:/Sample/bin}`

Then I selected the `.class` file and executed the `javap` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disassemble the currently selected `.class` file in Eclipse I use the following [arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7JpR.png) in the External Tools Configurations.

This way classes in subpackages of the `bin` folder can also be disassembled. The output is displayed in the Console view.

Oracle documentation of [javap parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Using javap command in eclipse]

In-addition to the valuable custom script suggested by @AlexR; the other way is : Open the terminal windows within the Ecplise and run the javap command with -p and other option.