# How do I read a Java class file (Java bytecode)

Tags: java

How do I view the contents of a .class file (java byte code)?

How do I open these type of files in Linux? I'm using Centos 5.8.

Comment: If you just want to view the binary or hex dump, you can use [od](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?od)

Comment: just want to see the code in the .class file.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`javap -c X` will show the disassembly of `X.class`.

Comment: using javap X -c worked ! Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

### Read bytecode

```
javap -v com.company.package.MainClass
```

To understand bytecode You can use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) list of mnemonics

Comment: +1 for the link to the online decompiler!

Answer (score 2):

You could [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) it.

To see Java source code check some decompiler. Go search for `jad`.

If you want to see bytecodes, just use `javap` which comes with the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

use javap. it's a part of the standard jdk.

Answer (score 0):

less filename.class

Not sure how it will help you, unless you can read byte code...

Comment: Geeee, I wanted to write that! But I think this would rather fit as a comment...

Comment: +1 for 'unless you can read byte code'

Comment: Chuck Norris _can_ read byte code. He can sing it too!

Answer (score 0):

Any binary file editor will do - [gHex](https://live.gnome.org/Ghex) or [xxd](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xxd.htm) are two recommendations.

Note, this won't really help you unless you can understand the bytecode given to you by the .class file...