# Why does a jar get corrupted if i change the bin folder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode, .class-file

I have a finished program which compiled successfully and works just fine. Out of interest, I wanted to see the bytecode in the project folder in eclipse (under the bin folder). I accidentally saved it as a .txt rather than a .class and now the jar file won't work!
It's not an issue, i've fixed it but why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's simply because you changed the file extension, Eclipse couldn't find the .class file, and so it considered the .jar corrupt.

The output of a Java compiler is not executable code, but is actually bytecode. If Eclipse can't find this bytecode, it cannot execute your code.

I've found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172477/2637416) that shows a plugin that will allow you to view bytecode using Eclipse in the future.

Comment: but won't a jar run standalone with just the JRE? If so why would the project folder have anything to do with the finished jar?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking. Am I right in saying you exported your Java Project as a .jar and then changed the file extension of a class file in the project?

Comment: I must have done something i guess, tell me if i'm wrong.

Comment: You're right. That is odd. Was it a runnable jar file or just a library?